# email address verifies but creates account although if email address is invalid

Tags: javascript

I wrote script for email address verification and it gives alert notification if invalid email is given. Although the account is created with the same invalid email address and stored in the database...please help
code seems to be:

```
    <div class="form">

    <ul class="tab-group">
    <li class="tab "><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">


    <form name="form1" action="trynow" method="post" onsubmit="ValidateEmail(document.form1.txtEmail)">
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="register_csrf" autocomplete="false" autofocus="false" value="<%=((String)request.getAttribute("register_csrf")!=null)?request.getAttribute("register_csrf"):"" %>"/>

            <% String error_msg = (String)request.getAttribute("error_msg");
                if(error_msg != null)
                {
            %>
            <div  class="alert alert-error"> <%= error_msg %></div>

            <% } %>
            <%= ((String)request.getAttribute("succ_msg") != null)?request.getAttribute("succ_msg"):"" %>

        </div>



            <div class="field-wrap">
                <label>
                    Full Name<span class="req">*</span>
                </label>
                <input required="required" name="txtName"  type="text" >
            </div>



            <div class="field-wrap">
                <label>
                    Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
                </label>
                <input required="required" name="txtEmail" type="text" >
            </div>

            <div class="field-wrap">
                <label>
                    Set A Password<span class="req">*</span>
                </label>
                <input name="txtPassword"  type="password" >
            </div>

            <div class="field-wrap">
                <label>
                    Retype Password<span class="req">*</span>
                </label>
                <input name="txtRePassword"  type="password" >
            </div>
            <div>
            <button type="submit" class="button button-block" />Get Started</button>
            </div>
        <a class="small-message" href="login"><small>Already Registered ?</small></a><a href="/"> <small> <br>Back To Home</small></a>
       </form>
        <script>
            function ValidateEmail(inputText)
            {
                var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
                if(inputText.value.match(mailformat))
                {
                    document.form1.txtEmail.focus();
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");
                    document.form1.text1.focus();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>

    </div><!-- tab-content -->

</div> <!-- /form -->
```

Comment: In body i wrote as: 
<body onload='document.form1.text1.focus()'>

Comment: There's no quotations around your var mailformat check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of **text1** write **txtEmail**

```
   <script>
                function ValidateEmail(inputText)
                {
                    var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
                    if(inputText.value.match(mailformat))
                    {
                        document.form1.txtEmail.focus();
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");
                        document.form1.txtEmail.focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your form onsubmit, use `return ValidateEmail(this.txtEmail)"`

```
<form name="form1" action="trynow" method="post" onsubmit="return ValidateEmail(this.txtEmail)">
```

Now only if the `email` is valid, the form submit will happen. Else it will be prevented.

Also you're referencing to `document.form1.text1.focus();`, whereas `text1` doesn't exist in the form at all. So you must be getting an error here as well.

Comment: Inside the function validateEmail, the OP is using `inputText.value` so need to pass just the element not the value in this case. You can refer `if(inputText.value.match(mail format))`

Comment: Ah, you are correct. But still you can use this.txtEmail

Comment: Ya that's true. We can reference the element in multiple ways. But i guess it's OPs choice in which OP is confident. As both will refer to same txtEmail i left it as such :)

Comment: Actually there are more errors in the page. See my answer

Comment: thanks #mohamedrias for ur precise answer...i guess i was too hurry to ask

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues, including not focusing the right field when the email is wrong and focusing something when it is not wrong as well.
I also would use test instead of match.

I suggest changing to this (in the head of the page):

```js
function ValidateEmail(inputText) {
  var val = inputText.value;
  var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
  if (!mailformat.test(val)) {
    alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");
    inputText.focus();
    return false;
  }
}
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementsByName("form1")[0].onsubmit=function() {
   return ValidateEmail(this.txtEmail);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
    <ul class="tab-group">
        <li class="tab "><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <form name="form1" action="trynow" method="post">
            <div>
                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <label>Full Name<span class="req">*</span>

                    </label>
                    <input required="required" name="txtName" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <label>Email Address<span class="req">*</span>

                    </label>
                    <input required="required" name="txtEmail" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <label>Set A Password<span class="req">*</span>

                    </label>
                    <input name="txtPassword" type="password">
                </div>
                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <label>Retype Password<span class="req">*</span>

                    </label>
                    <input name="txtRePassword" type="password">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" class="button button-block" />Get Started</button>
                </div> <a class="small-message" href="login"><small>Already Registered ?</small></a><a href="/"> <small> <br>Back To Home</small></a>

        </form>
        </div>
        <!-- tab-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /form -->
```

Comment: Just one correction, the OP has used class `.req` for labels as in                     `Retype Password<span class="req">*</span>` and in your validate function, you are checking `var reqs = document.querySelectorAll(".req");` which will return all span elements. Hope now my answer deserves an up vote ;)

Comment: Yes of course, but still the selector is wrong. The input is not inside span tag. As i mentioned earlier, `<span class="req">*</span>` doesn't contain the input but you have used `document.querySelectorAll(".req>input")`

Comment: Yes I see it. I have removed the tests for the other fields since it can easily be done in jQuery but looking for previous siblings is waste of time - a change to the html is needed for my loop to make sense. I missed the span on my mobile